# Intermediate von Neumann subalgebra of a $\sigma$-finite von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

I was confused the existence of the intermediate von Neumann subalgebra $P$ in the above Lemma.

We know that $M^{\varphi}$ and $M$ must be globally invariant under $\sigma^{\varphi}$. Can we construct any another $P$ such that $P\neq M$ and $P\neq M^{\varphi}$, in addition,
$P$ is globally invariant under $\sigma^{\varphi}$?

Comment: May I know this excerpt is from which book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a concrete example, but at least I can give some heuristics why this is not unexpected at all.

Given $x\in M\setminus M^\varphi$ selfadjoint, you can construct (writing $\sigma$ instead of $\sigma^\varphi$ for clarity)
$$
P=(M^\varphi\cup\{\sigma^\varphi_t(x):\ t\in\mathbb R\})''.
$$
I guess without more concrete information about $x$ there might be situations where $P=M$, but at least it shows you a possibility for algebra that is invariant for $\sigma$ but different from $M^\varphi$.

Comment: Suppose $y=\sigma(x)$, for any $t\in \Bbb R$, according to your construction, $\sigma_t^{\varphi}(y)$ may not belong to $P$.

Comment: I wrote as if the action was discrete and not continuous. The point was for you to see how an algebra can be invariant and strictly larger than $M^\varphi$.

Comment: If $M^{\varphi}$ is a type II$_1$ factor, Can we find a partial isometry $v\in M$ such that $vv^*+v^*v=1$  and $v\varphi=\lambda \varphi v$, where $0＜\lambda＜1$, then we take $x=v$ in the above, and get $P$ constructed above is globally invariant?

Comment: Such a $v$ would certainly work as my $x$. I wouldn't know how to argue that $P$ is a proper subalgebra, though.

Comment: If $M^{\varphi}$ is a type II$_1$ factor,   can we deduce that there exists a partial isometry $v$ such that $vv^*+v^*v=1$?

Comment: Yes, take any projection $p$ with trace $\frac12$. Then $1-p$ also as trace $\frac12$ and so they are equivalent and there exists a partial isometry $v$ with $v^*v=p$ and $vv^*=1-p$.

Comment: Until now, I cannot  see why the partial isometry $v$ satisfying $vv^*+v^*v=1$ and $v\varphi=\lambda \varphi v$,where $0＜\lambda＜1$.

Comment: If we know that there exists a partial isometry $w$ such that $w\varphi=\lambda \varphi w$, where $0＜\lambda＜1$, can we construct a partial isometry $v$ by $w$ such that the above conditions are satisied?

Comment: No idea. $ \ \ $

Comment: Can we consider it as following: For $0＜\lambda＜1$, there exist projections $p,q\in M^{\varphi}$ such that $\varphi(p)=\frac{1}{1+\lambda}$ and $\varphi(q)=\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}$, then we have $p\sim1-q$. Hence there exist a partial isometry $v$ such that $v^*v=p$ and $vv^*=1-q$. According to $v^*v, 1-vv^*\in M^{\varphi}$, can we conclude that $\sigma_t^{\varphi}(v)=\lambda^{it} v$ for any $t\in \Bbb R$?

Comment: It cannot be that simple. The equality $v^*v+vv^*=1$ is impossible, since it implies $q=p$ and hence $\lambda=1$. Besides, if $v\in M^\varphi$ then $\sigma^\varphi_t(v)=v$.

Comment: I have written the email to ask the author of that paper for help and received no reply.